Как обрабатывать все боты одним скриптом при помощи webhook
Суть вопроса вот в чем, у меня на сайте есть скрипт, я хочу чтобы он принимал запросы с двух разных ботов. Как такое сделать? И можно ли вообще?

Можно. Но здесь вам никто не напишет с нуля то что вы хотите. Для таких задач есть фриланс.

@YaMus я просто не могу понять, если я для 2 - 4 ботов укажу один и тот же webhook будет ли оно работать, и второй момент как определить какой бот присылает на скрипт данные. Просто лень под каждый бот дублировать скрипт.

для начала покажите ваш код

Количество ботов не принципиально, главное, что бы отправка была корректная и что бы  отправлялись данные в том виде, в котором ожидает их принять ваш скрипт
